# Entity Selection Going Outside of Specified Range

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am having an issue where I am trying to assign a score to an entity if it is within range of another specified entity. My issue is that all entities will be given the score, not only the ones that are withing range. It should only be given to the entities that are around the one with the score of `burnTimer`.

Here are my commands in order:

```
/entitydata @e[score_target.fire_min=1] {Fire:20}

/execute @e[score_target.fire_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[score_target.fire_min=1] burnTimer 25

/execute @e[score_burnTimer_min=5] ~0.5 ~ ~-0.5 scoreboard players set @e[dx=-1,dy=0,dz=1,team=!Players] burnChained 1

/entitydata @e[score_burnChained_min=1] {Fire:20}
```

Not quite sure what is causing this, but it would be great if someone knew any way to fix the issue. Again, only the entities within the range of the one with `burnTimer` should be given the score of `burnChained`.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up having to make a command to limit the `burnChained`.

```
/scoreboard players set @e[score_burnTimer=0,score_burnTimer_min=0] burnChained 0
```

This will make it so that once the `burnTimer` runs out that the chain will stop spreading. So that is working, but now I am having the problem where it isn't giving them the initial score because it isn't reading my `rightClick`. The initial score being `target.fire`.